# String theory online resources

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I am a calculus 3 student (just starting multivariable calculus) and going to start out with linear algebra. I also am pretty knowledgable on classical mechanics (such as the Lagrangian, Hamiltonian equations, and Possion brackets) and quantum mechanics. At this level, what are some good resources to learn about string theory and quantum gravity? I would like it to be free, online resources that include some math that is at my level.

Comment: Hi T Abraham, Resource recom questions are restricted on Phys.SE, cf. various meta posts, to e.g. avoid Phys.SE becoming a link farm. For online lectures on ST, you may try searching [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=string+theory+lecture).

Comment: @Qmechanic i didn't know that! I read the policy on resource recommendation questions and it allowed these type of questions... did it change recently?

Comment: It used to effectively not be allowed, but now Phys.SE allows some.